# VB.NET Concurrency Exception with DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have encountered a  with my datagridview, I bound it to a datatable and am calling and the handler on row is as follows

```
Dim cmdBuild As New SqlCommandBuilder(sda)
sda.Update(dgv.DataSource)
```

> sda is SqlDataAdapter

so the problem is it works fine, any changes are updated to the database, but the concurrency exception pops up and I understand it is due to updating a ghost row in the database, now what I don't know is how do I go about it, how do I prevent it from happening. spent a lot of time on this one thing so any help that will sort me out will be ***HIGHLY*** appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**P.S. If more code is needed I'll post it.**

**Edit**

```
Public Sub editUsers(ByRef mainPanel As CustomTabControl, ByRef dt As System.Data.DataTable)
        For i As Integer = 0 To mainPanel.TabCount - 1
            If mainPanel.TabPages(i).Text = "Excel users" Then
                mainPanel.SelectedTab = mainPanel.TabPages(i)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        Dim tb As New TabPage("Excel users")

        Dim datagrid As New DataGridView
        datagrid.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow)
        datagrid.DataSource = dt
        AddHandler datagrid.RowLeave, AddressOf Home.dataUpdate

        tb.Controls.Add(datagrid)
        datagrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        mainPanel.TabPages.Add(tb)
        mainPanel.SelectedTab = tb

        datagrid.Columns("ID").Visible = False
        datagrid.Columns("Username").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        datagrid.Columns("Username").FillWeight = 45
        datagrid.Columns("Password").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        datagrid.Columns("Password").FillWeight = 45
    End Sub

Public Sub dataUpdate()
        Dim dgv As DataGridView = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To mainPanel.TabCount - 1
            If mainPanel.TabPages(i).Text = "Excel users" Then
                dgv = mainPanel.TabPages(i).Controls(0)
            End If
        Next

        If IsNothing(dgv) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For i As Integer = dgv.DataSource.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If dgv.DataSource.Rows(i).RowState = DataRowState.Deleted Then
                Continue For
            End If
            If IsDBNull(dgv.DataSource.Rows(i).Item(1)) Or IsDBNull(dgv.DataSource.Rows(i).Item(2)) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        Dim cmdBuild As New SqlCommandBuilder(sda)
        sda.Update(dgv.DataSource)

        dgv.DataSource.Rows.Add(dtt.NewRow)
    End Sub
```

The code above is all the code that is involved with datagridview control

Comment: are you using any kind of database locks ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just updated my code, have a look @Stavm

Comment: Instead of using adapter - you can update rows manually, then if row not exists query will return "affected rows = 0"